# Storybook 7 render list of component

Tags: storybook

Hi I'm building my own UI library with storybook. I recently move to storybook 7 latest version and I was wondering if they were a better/cleaner way to do:

```js
const props = { children: "Click here", buttonType: ButtonType.PRIMARY };
export const Size: Story = {
  args: {
    children: "Click here",
    buttonType: ButtonType.PRIMARY,
  },
  decorators: [
    () => (
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-5">
        <Button {...{ ...props, size: ButtonSize.SMALL }} />
        <Button {...{ ...props, size: ButtonSize.MEDIUM }} />
        <Button {...{ ...props, size: ButtonSize.LARGE }} />
        <Button {...{ ...props, size: ButtonSize.CONTENT_SIZE }} />
      </div>
    ),
  ],
};
```

I'm adding args to my Story but no using them because I only change the size field.

Thanks for your help